# How To display Sql Server timestamp column in kendo grid java script

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

i have a timestamp column in one of my sql server table for maintaining row versioning , 
but i dont know how to display its value on kendo grid ,
this is required because my entities wont updating records  with null values in that column , by displaying timestamp value on grid , i will take it back when updating records .
 this is my kendo grid schema

```
 schema: {
            errors: function(response) {
                if (response.Voucher && response.Voucher !== "True") {
                    return response.Voucher;
                }
                return false;
            },
            data: "data",
            total: "total",
            model: {
                id: "ID",
                fields: {
                    ID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                    FK_Category_ID: { defaultValue: -1, validation: { required: { message: "" } } },
                    CompanynameAr: { type: "string", validation: { required: { message: " " } } },
                    CompanynameEn: { type: "string" },
                    FK_Country_ID: { defaultValue: -1, validation: { required: { message: "" } } },

                    Address: { type: "string", validation: { required: { message: "" } } },
                    PoBox: { type: "string" },
                    Contractno: { type: "number", validation: { required: { message: "" },min:0 } },
                    Refrence: { type: "number",validation:{min:0}},
                    RemarksMarketing: { type: "string" },
                    Active: { type: "string" },
                    Latitude: { type: "string" },
                    Longitude: { type: "string" },
                    RowVersion: {
                        type: "date", parse: function (value) {
                            return new Date(value * 1000);
                        }
                    }

                    //Address
                }
            }
        }
```

here RowVersion is my column that hold timestamp values , parse function is just hit and try for solving particular issue but wont sucessful .  so help needed

Answer (score 1):

At the server-side, when adding or updating a record, you should NOT include the timestamp (RowVersion) column in your query (even with a `NULL` value). SQL Server will automatically generate the value for the RowVersion column on each change to any record. So if you are using plain SQL, remove RowVersion from your SQL; Or if you use Entity Framework Code-First, you may use a `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]` attribute to inform Entity Framework that it should not update the related column.

Anyway, if you want to display the timestamp (rowversion) value to your user, it is an 8-byte auto-incrementing integer that is usually mapped to a `byte[]` type and you may use `BitConverter.ToInt64()` to convert it to a `long` and show it to the user. But you never need to receive it in your controller on add/update requests because you should not include it in your query.

Answer (score 0):

As you could see on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx), an sql server Timestamp value is a .net byte array, so you can't convert it to a Date value.

You can simply make no convertion on the received value and just hide it.

Comment: what will be data type ? because i have to receive this value on action of controller ..